# How to exclude video from applying a style sheet?

Tags: css, safari

Safari doesn’t have build-in “dark theme” or night mode extension like Chrome, so it really hurts when I need to do homework in a dark room (when my roommates are sleeping). Thankfully Safari can change its default css sheet in preference. So I wrote something as follows,

```
* {
color: rgb(176, 176,176) !important;
background: #000000  !important;
```

}

```
a:link {
color: rgb(99,202,67)!important;
```

}

It generally works great but there is a major issue. 
All videos become all black and cannot be watched.

I tried to use :not() selector to exclude video from applying vvbackground: #000000  !important, but it doesn't work.

```
*:not(.container) {
color: rgb(176, 176,176) !important;
background: #000000  !important;
```

}
[The element from the video page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymCHJ.png)

**container** is the name of the class when I inspected the element. Not sure whether it is right.

Longing for suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can reset a CSS property with `inherit`.

Try adding a new selector for the video and set `color` and `background` to `inherit`

But in general, setting **all** elements to black might be not a great idea here as you also make transparent elements become intransparent.

A better way would be to only set certain elements to be black

Comment: I tried to add the following codes. It doesn't work.                                 '.container *{
    color:inherit;
    background:inherit;
}'

Comment: Just added it. No effect. Is it the problem of .container? I tried to add video{ color:inherit !important; background:inherit !important; } and * not:(video) or * not:(.container). Still all black.

Comment: Hi lumio, The problem was solved by @Samuel Escapa through selecting .container and using background : transparent . I am wondering why your method(inherit) and mine(using :not(.container) didn't work. Any ideas?